# SlotMachine game as first Android app

Tags: java, game, android

After learning a bit of Android Java I've chosen to make a tiny game so that I can use the learned techniques in a real app.

I had the idea of a [slot machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slot_machine) simulator:

You press a button and it generates three random numbers. The sum of the random numbers becomes your final result and a sound is played. Depending on the result a message is displayed.

[image: Before starting a game.]

[image: After starting a game.]

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.michael.slotmachine;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvSum;
    TextView tvRoll1;
    TextView tvRoll2;
    TextView tvRoll3;
    Random random;
    MediaPlayer mp3Player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init of object-props goes here ...
        tvSum       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSum);
        tvRoll1     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRoll1);
        tvRoll2     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRoll2);
        tvRoll3     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRoll3);
        random      = new Random();
        mp3Player   = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
        // -------------------------------------------------------
    }

    public void processGame(View v) {
        // Do the math ...
        int roll1 = 1 + random.nextInt(7);
        int roll2 = 1 + random.nextInt(7);
        int roll3 = 1 + random.nextInt(7);

        int rollsSum = roll1 + roll2 + roll3;

        // ... then write the results to the UI.
        tvRoll1.setText("" + roll1);
        tvRoll2.setText("" + roll2);
        tvRoll3.setText("" + roll3);

        tvSum.setText("" + rollsSum);

        v.setEnabled(false);    // Disable the 'Spin Roll'-Button.

        mp3Player.start();      // Play the MP3-file.

        // ---- Pop-Up Message -------
        String message;

        if (rollsSum < 10) {
            message = "Better luck next time.";
        } else if (rollsSum < 15) {
            message = "Respectable result.";
        } else if (rollsSum < 21) {
            message = "You have done great.";
        } else {
            message = "You have hit the Jackpot.";
        }

        Toast toast  = Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        // ------------------------------
    }

    public void recreateGame(View v) {
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRoll1"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40px"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRoll2"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40px"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRoll3"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40px"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewYourScore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40px"
            android:layout_weight="0.11"
            android:text="Your Score:"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40px"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSpin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:onClick="processGame"
            android:text="Spin Roll"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNewGame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50px"
            android:onClick="recreateGame"
            android:text="New Game"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is my code done in a good fashion? Are there points which I should improve?

Comment: Not really a code problem, but your logic is not how a slot machine works.  You don't sum the numbers, you win if they match certain patterns, e.g. three sevens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Clear state rather than restart

You use this function to restart the game:

> ```
> public void recreateGame(View v) {
>     finish();
>     startActivity(getIntent());
> }
> ```

This recreates the activity.
I don't think this is a recommended practice.
I think it would be better to restore the initial state of the view elements.
The same method that does that could also be used for the initial setup.

#### Initializing `Random`

It's not a big deal,
but since the instance of `Random` doesn't depend on the call to `onCreate`,
I would initialize it at the time of declaration.
That way I surely won't forget to initialize it later.

#### Unnecessary local variable

The local `toast` variable is unnecessary here,
you could drop it and call `.show()` directly chained after `.makeText(...)`.

```
Toast.makeText(
    getApplicationContext(),
    message,
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
        // Do the math ...
```

Doesn't provide much explanation. I would instead say:

```
        // Roll 3 dice and collect their sum.
```

To illustrate what the random numbers are doing.

Same goes for:

```
        mp3Player.start();      // Play the MP3-file.
```

What MP3-file? What does this have to do with the slot machine?

This comment:

```
       v.setEnabled(false);    // Disable the 'Spin Roll'-Button.
```

is pretty good, it tells me what this line of code does in terms of the role it plays in the slot machine.

Answer (score 4):

Overall it seems clear enough. I'd like to quibble with a pair of method names, these callback handlers:

```
public void processGame(View v) ...
```

and

```
public void recreateGame(View v) ...
```

It's good advice to strive for "boring" in many aspects of software engineering, especially in android development. The identifiers `buttonSpin` and `buttonNewGame` are terrific. They're clear, concise, and they match the on-screen appearance, so they're easy to find. Reuse such names in related parts of an app. I'd recommend naming your handlers `onSpin` and `onNewGame`.

I agree with Janos about sticking to recommended practice. See also https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#alc